# where can i find data-target for a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

A recently developed Laravel app has been handed down to me and I'm trying to find out where can this `data-target` be found:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTravelHistory">Add Travel History</button>
```

Where should I be able to find `#addTravlHistory` in Laravel files? I'm ultimately trying to recreate another modal.

Comment: you could find that in the same file or search in `resources/views` folder for div with an id of `addTravelHistory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a Modal with Id `addTravelHistory`, in the document., What this button do is, on clicking the button it will trigger the modal with ID `addTravelHistory`,

As you are new to that set of code, it will be in `path/to/the/root/resources/views/` diectory.

Either the modal is included or written in some other `.blade.php` files or the may be the Modal itself can be a `.blade.php` file.

Hope this Helps